# Doctrine findBy with OR condition

Tags: doctrine-orm, findby

Is it possible to use `OR` statement in Doctrine `findBy()` method?
I know that given array is interpreted as `case1 AND case2...`
Like this

```
$this->repos['notif']->findBy(array('status' => 1, 'status' => 2, 'status' => 3);
```

Stands for

```
SELECT * FROM `notif` WHERE status=1 AND status=2 AND status=3;
```

Now I need something to stand for:

```
SELECT * FROM `notif` WHERE status=1 OR status=2 OR status=3;
```

Is there a way to get all cases?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know this is not a supported feature by Doctrine to use IN() queries with findby. You could do two things:

1. Implement a `findByStatus(array $statusTypes)` method in your (custom) 'notif' repository class. If you like this approach I can give you a example.
2. Convert your findBy to the following:

   ```
   $qb = $this->repos['notif']->createQueryBuilder('n');
   $data = $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('status', array(1,2,3)))->getQuery()->getResult();
   ```

That should work either :)

Answer (score 188):

You can write:

```
$this->repos['notif']->findBy(array('status' => array(1, 2, 3)));
```

and that should work too.

Comment: What if I want to apply OR between different columns

Comment: @KetavChotaliya then you go with a custom query builder in the repository

Answer (score 23):

I know that this is old question. Anyways, it's possible to use `Criteria` for the complex queries (in Doctrine 2 at least):

```
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
$criteria
  ->orWhere($criteria->expr()->contains('domains', 'a'))
  ->orWhere($criteria->expr()->contains('domains', 'b'));

$groups = $em
  ->getRepository('Group')
  ->matching($criteria);
```

Comment: For those who downvote, please leave comments to help others understand your decision. Thanks

Comment: How can you add criteria and sort by and limit rules to the repository also? Can you share an example? Right now, the SQL in your example would only add where clauses, how do we add limit & orderby?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan maybe, unfortunately I have no idea for now and have no project to test it at this moment. But are there any mentions of the limit or orderby in the author's question?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan Maybe no longer relevant, but for future reference `Criteria` has an `orderBy`

Comment: @gorodezkiy 
this not works because:
`Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findBy() must be of the type array, object given`

Answer (score 9):

If **you are using MongoDB** and need more complex queries, like "less than" linked together with OR, but cannot use a query builder, this also works with this syntax:

```
   ->findBy(array(
                '$or' => array(
                    array('foo' => array('$lt' => 1234)),
                    array('$and' => array(
                        array('bar' => 45678),
                        array('baz' => array('$lt' => 89013))
                    ))
                )
    ));
```

Or as a solution for your question:

```
   ->findBy(array(
                '$or' => array(
                    array('status' => 1),
                    array('status' => 2),
                    array('status' => 3),
                )
    ));
```

Comment: This does not work in the case outlined in the question. Isn't this mongodb specific syntax?

Comment: I haven't used MongoDB with doctrine, but that is definitely MongoDB syntax.

Comment: You are right, but this is passed through. I use this code in production with Doctrine and Symphony and it works (seems to be passed through) and returns correct results. This is my stack ... 

  "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
  "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "dev-master",
  "doctrine/mongodb": "dev-master",
  "ext-mongo": "*",

Comment: I can also say that this does not work with non mongoDB setups.

Comment: Whoopsie. Yes! I thought the question was mongodb specific. Will note this in my answer!