# Logical OR in doctrine2 getRepository->findBy()

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can write query like in doctrine2

`SELECT * from table where field = value1 or field = value2`

I found something like

```
 $em->getRepository('myentitity')
           ->findBy(
               array('field' => 'value1','field'=>'value2'),        // $where 
             );
```

But I think it is AND .. Please suggest me
Thanks

Comment: This will help :https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=getRepository

Comment: @NiladriDas I already had a look there but cant get what I want

Comment: see condition operator http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#conditional-operators  you can use `in` for this and see this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259089/doctrine-findby-with-or-condition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
  $em->getRepository('myentitity')
       ->findBy(
           array('field' =>array( 'value1','value2'))        // $where 
         );
```

If you pass an array of values Doctrine will convert the query into a WHERE field IN (..) query automatically: