# Doctrine2 findBy with OR instead of AND

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Similiar to [Logical OR in doctrine2 getRepository->findBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621483/logical-or-in-doctrine2-getrepository-findby) but no duplicate.

Duplicate of [doctrine2 findby two columns OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229609/doctrine2-findby-two-columns-or-condition?rq=1) but I am asking for a `findBy` -way **without the QueryBuilder**.

```
SELECT * from table where CUSTOMER = value1 or SHOP = value2
```

This builds the WHERE condition with an `AND`

```
$em->getRepository('myentitity')
       ->findBy(
           array('CUSTOMER' => 'value1', 'SHOP'=>'value2'),
         );
```

How to get `findBy` results with `OR` ?

Important: The number of fields is not the same on every request.

Comment: Why the seemingly arbitrary restriction to not use a QueryBuilder?